# Weird Characters from CSV Import

Tags: php

I'm importing text from a .csv file. When importing the file there are some weird characters in it like "Õ". The character is supposed to be in apostrophe. For instance "it's". Any idea how I can convert that to a standard apostrophe?

I'm pretty sure that they problem is from the source .csv, but I need to be need to be able convert these characters.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running into "[smart quotes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-HP005190124.aspx)" issues.  I believe [Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/about) has [an exact solution to your problem](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php):

```
<?php
function convert_smart_quotes($string)
{
    $search = array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151));
    $replace = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-');
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
?>
```

Comment: That did not seem to have any effect. The apostrophe is now a �.

Comment: If it helps I just noticed that this is also happening to some spaces as well.

Comment: Perhaps the input string is in some sort of Unicode encoding? (UTF-8?)

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like codepage issue. http://www.justskins.com/forums/character-switching-problem-47590.html shows an example of CP1252 and MacRoman. Try using iconv?